Getting weird errors regarding column names inside a Patch function in Power Apps
I have two lists. Equipment Inventory' list and 'EI - Oakland, CA' has these exact column names: EquipmentName, EquipmentID, PhoneNumber, EquipmentType, Status, Email, CheckedOutBy, CheckOutDate, CheckOutTime, CheckInDate, CheckInTime, LastCheckedOutBy, LastCondition, Condition, UnitNumber.
I get the error "The specified column 'CheckOutTime' does not exist. The column with the most similar name is 'CheckOuttime'". When I change it to CheckOuttime, I then get the error "The specified column 'CheckedOutBy' does not exist. The column with the most similar name is 'Checkoutoutby'" However foundItem.CheckedOutBy works. This is so weird.
If(
    LookUp(Switch(
        selectedBranch.BranchLocation,
        "Seattle, WA", 'Equipment Inventory',
        "Oakland, CA", 'EI - Oakland, CA',
        'Equipment Inventory'
        // Add more cases here for other branches...
    ), 'EquipmentName' = foundItem.EquipmentName).Status = "Available",

    // Update the 'Equipment Inventory' list
    Patch(
        Switch(
        selectedBranch.BranchLocation,
        "Seattle, WA", 'Equipment Inventory',
        "Oakland, CA", 'EI - Oakland, CA',
        'Equipment Inventory'
        // Add more cases here for other branches...
    ),
        foundItem,
        {
            'CheckedOutBy': User().FullName,
            'LastCheckedOutBy': foundItem.CheckedOutBy,
            'CheckOutDate': Now(),
            'CheckOutTime': Text(Now(), "hh:mm AM/PM"),
            Status: "Unavailable",
            'CheckInDate': Blank(), // Clear 'Check In Date'
            'CheckInTime': "" // Clear 'Check In Time'
        }
    )
);

Im expecting CheckedOutBy in both the lists to be updated with the user's full name. But Power Apps doesn't think the column exits, and it claims that it is actually called Checkoutoutby which is total nonsense.

Nevermind I solved it, the coumn names were correct, but for some reason the specific column URL's where CheckOuttime and Checkoutoutby
